# php - conditional where clause and mysql parameters

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I've got a form with several different fields used for a search function in my application. There can be any combination for the search parameters, all could be filled or just 1 (or any other).

As of now, the relevant part of the PHP code looks like this (which actually works - but I fear and thinks is a terribly bad design/implementation):

```
       $whereClause =  "";
        if (!empty($_POST['searchAlias'])) {
            $searchAlias = "%{$_POST['searchAlias']}%";
            $whereClause .= " AND (users.alias LIKE ? OR users.alias LIKE ?)";
        } else {
            $searchAlias = "";
            $whereClause .= " AND (users.alias LIKE ? OR users.alias LIKE ?)";
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['searchLink'])) {
            $searchLink = "%{$_POST['searchLink']}%";
            $whereClause .= " AND (posts.homepage LIKE ? OR posts.homepage LIKE ?)";
        } else {
            $searchLink = "";
            $whereClause .= " AND (posts.homepage LIKE ? OR ? = '')";
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['searchComment'])) {
            $searchComment = "%{$_POST['searchComment']}%";
            $whereClause .= " AND (posts.comment LIKE ? OR posts.comment LIKE ?)";
        } else {
            $searchComment = "";
            $whereClause .= " AND (posts.comment LIKE ? OR ? = '')";
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['searchCategory'])) {
            $searchCategory = $_POST['searchCategory'];
            $whereClause .= " AND (posts.category LIKE ? OR posts.category LIKE ?)";
        } else {
            $searchCategory = "";
            $whereClause .= " AND (posts.category LIKE ? OR ? = '')";
        }

        $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT users.alias, posts.postId, 
        categories.category, posts.homepage, posts.comment, posts.timestamp, 
        posts.upvotes FROM ((posts INNER JOIN categories ON posts.category = 
        categories.id) INNER JOIN users ON posts.userId = users.userId) 
        WHERE 1=1 $whereClause ORDER BY postId DESC LIMIT 300");


        $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $searchAlias,$searchAlias, 
        $searchLink,$searchLink, $searchComment,$searchComment, 
        $searchCategory,$searchCategory);
```

I should add that I also have 2 date input fields (from and to date) which can be included in the search as well, they are not added in the current php code since I haven't fixed them yet.

As you can see I make sure that the parameters set from the form data are appended to the whereClause - always with two ? to make sure the bind_param types and variables can remain the same all the time.

So, is this an "acceptable" solution or is there any way to make this a lot cleaner and simpler? I've tried searching for different solutions but im either not good enough searching, or not smart enough understanding the solutions.

Any help or idea is appreciated!

Kind regards,
Eken

Comment: `OR ? = ''` That is definitely not legal and will cause compilation errors

Comment: For the ? = '' would only work if ? is replaced by a literal and not a column name. If you need to test for a value being empty, do that in the PHP code, and omit from the SQL code. You would be better served using named parameters in PDO. That way you could build your where clause, then bind all possible parameters. Those not in the SQL statement would be ignored.

Comment: Using PDO named parameters would also eliminate the need to duplicate some of your comparisons. I would change to PDO, and setup an array of $_POST names to test, and where clause pieces (without the ANDs), then loop through them, building an array of clauses. After the loop, explode the array join the pieces with " AND " to get your final where clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments guys, as I thought, my solution is not a good one, I'll try to dig into understanding the PDO concept/solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PDO with named parameters would make this task a bit easier to maintain if/when additional search parameters are added. It would also accommodate search parameters where the value is compared to multiple columns, or require type casting of the search value. You may want to consider adding '%' before and after the values for LIKE conditions. This could be done by adding the $_POST values to an array and binding the array values instead of the $_POST values.

**EDIT**

I've modified my first posting to search for a matching date, and to allow adding wildcards to like comparisons. The code could also be easily modified to allow for two value checks like between dates.

```
$postVals = array();
foreach($_POST as $varname => $varval) {
    $postVals[$varname] = $varval;
}
$wherePieces = array();
$tests = array(
    "searchAlias" => array("where" => "user.alias LIKE :searchAlias","addWildCard" => false),
    "searchLink" => array("where" => "posts.homepage LIKE :searchLink","addWildCard" => true),
    "searchComment" => array("where" => "posts.comment LIKE :searchComment","addWildCard" => true),
    "searchCategory" => array("where" => "posts.category LIKE :searchCategory","addWildCard" => false),
    "searchTimestamp" => array("where" => "CAST(posts.timestamp AS DATE) = CAST(:searchTimestamp AS DATE)","addWildCard" => false)
);

foreach($tests as $postname => $wherePart) {
    if(isset($_POST[$postname]) && $_POST[$postname] != '') {
        $wherePieces[] = $wherePart['where'];
    }
}
$whereClause = "WHERE " . implode(" AND ",$wherePieces);
$qstr = "SELECT 
            users.alias, 
            posts.postId, 
            categories.category, 
            posts.homepage, 
            posts.comment, 
            posts.timestamp, 
            posts.upvotes 
        FROM posts 
        INNER JOIN categories 
            ON posts.category = categories.id
        INNER JOIN users 
            ON posts.userId = users.userId) 
        $whereClause 
        ORDER BY postId DESC 
        LIMIT 300";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($qstr);
foreach($tests as $postname => $wherePart) {
    if(isset($_POST[$postname]) && $_POST[$postname] != '') {
        if($wherePart["addWildCard"]) {
            $postVals[$postname] = '%'.$postVals[$postname].'%';
        }
        $stmt->bindParam(':'.$postname,$postVals[$postname]);
    }
}
$stmt->execute();
```

**NOTE:** Not tested, could have typos.

Comment: Wow, thank you. This is some heavy duty PHP/Mysql code. I'm still a rookie when it comes to this so I'll need some time to analyze/understand how all the parts of this works. Using your code as is (except for editing the $qtr var to $qstr I gives me a bindParam error (Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean)

 If I understood this right, would/should this code work as long as I use "searchAlias" and so fourth as POST parameters? (Which I'm doing). And would the timestamp work when I have two different POST paramters (from date and to date in YYYY-MM-DD format?).

Comment: Update: I do now understand the concept & code. I hadn't understood the difference between mysqli and PDO, so no wonder the mysqli connection didn't work. However, now I've added a PDO connection which works fine. 

I've managed to get the query firing when I fill in all the input fields as well as setting the wildcard to false. When I set wildcard to true it seems to fail binding the parameters. (Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in).

When I don't fill in all the values I get the following: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in.

Comment: Yep, I didn't think about the wildcard part enough. Basically, the 2nd parameter to the bind should be a variable. So, instead of binding to the $_POST, you would create an array to put the $_POST values in, and add the wildcards to the value in that variable. I'll update the code shortly.

Comment: I also fixed the problem with the bind. It only binds those parameters that are present. So now you should be able to pass from none to all of the filters.

Comment: If you want to implement a date range, you'll need to test for one of the fields from the form in this code, and on the page, use JS to ensure that both exist if the one you test for exists. This code will only test for one field being passed, so the page would need to validate that both exists before submitting the data to this page.

Comment: You're a scripting machine! Everything works flawlessly, I just added a check which checks if all POST values are empty, if true I change the WHERE clause to "". (Keyup live search - gets everything if search inputs are blank). Also had a slight problem with the bindParam (only last POST value was used) before your idea with the array (worked with bindValue). But now everything is perfect.

So, I'll go ahead and mark this one as the accepted answer, and also say a big, big thank you to you. Without your excellent help I'd struggle with this for a very long time. 

Highly appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help! Hope the rest of your project goes smoothly!